# Reading a local file with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-io

I'm trying to read a local file from my file system using javascript but I just can't get it to work. I've tried the following approaches below:

```
//Approach 1
function onInitFs(fs) {
        alert(fs.root.fullPath);
        fs.root.getFile('/test.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {

        // Get a File object representing the file,
        // then use FileReader to read its contents.
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onloadend = function(e) {
             alert(this.result);
           };

           reader.readAsText(file);
        }, errorHandler);

      }, errorHandler);

    }

    //Approach 2
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","test.txt",false);
          xmlhttp.send();
          xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

But for each approach I'm told that the file can't be found. The path for the file itself is "C:\test.txt". I've tried prepending "file:" to the path but with no success. I've tried each approach on IE, Mozilla and Chrome.
I've looked at each of the threads below but still can't find the answer. Any ideas?

[xmlhttprequest for local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683596/xmlhttprequest-for-local-files)

[Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)

[XMLHttpRequest not working (blank page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810218/xmlhttprequest-not-working-blank-page)

[Read file:// URLs in IE XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142156/read-file-urls-in-ie-xmlhttprequest)

[Read a local file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401215/read-a-local-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Where are you reading the file? I just see some AJAX. Did you copy the right code?

Comment: Don't the last three lines of approach 2 read the file?

Answer (score 0):

For *Gecko*, from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs)

> Starting in Gecko 1.9, files are allowed to read only certain other files.  Specifically, a file can read another file only if the parent directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the target file. Directories cannot be loaded this way, however.

This means an *XMLHttpRequest* in (e.g.) Firefox which has an origin of `C:\foo\bar.html` can only access `C:\foo\x` where `x` is some path.

Other browsers will have similar restrictions or be even more restricted for the *file:* protocol. It is much easier if you run a server and load from that.

Comment: I've tried placing the 'test.txt' file in the same directory as the file that's attempting to do the reading but still no success. I'm this as part of an application where files are created using Java and then read using Javascript so I'd have to upload the files automatically in Java. Are there any server packages that support that kind of functionality that are also free?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `file://` or any absolute path, you can put your file in server environment, so maybe it will have a path like: `localhost:8080/ROOT/test.txt`

Because some browsers don't support reading local files with Javascript, only is not security.